# how to handle form-data on expressJs sent from postman

Tags: node.js, express, postman, multer

I am developing API to accept files and form data which will be sent from react, So I am using **form-data** type in **Postman** to test my API, but the error that I am getting is:

```
Error: WHERE parameter "email" has invalid "undefined" value
```

and also my `req.body` is empty
I am using **multer** to handle files.
I have already added these in my server file:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(cors());
```

Here's a screenshot of my postman request (not yet sending files)

[image: Postman request Image]

Comment: How are yo accessing email param In your server side?

Comment: Consider using [multer](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/multer.html)